# Computers are restarting spontaneously and simultaneously, how do I find the cause?

Tags: centos, troubleshooting

I have two computers that spontaneously shut down and rebooted (this happened more than once), both are identical hardware and were installed from the same image (CentOS 5). They are controlling some equipment, and each shutdown is a significant annoyance and waste of money.

The logs don't give any clue, I can only determine that it is not a clean restart, but behaves like a spontaneous loss of power. There is no entry at all that is typical for a controlled shutdown as initiated by `init 0` or `init 6`, just the entries typical for booting the computer. The computers also don't go out completely, but they boot again.

I'm reasonably certain that it is not a human intervening, though I can't be absolutely certain. A power loss or fluctuation is also unlikely as the computers are the only equipment affected each time, and they are also in different parts of the building. There are no cronjobs executing at the time of the shutdowns.

I'm now trying to find out if it is a hardware defect, or a software-initiated problem. But from what I know, a kernel panic should not restart the computer but leave the panic message on the screen.

Which kind of software errors could cause the computer to spontaneously restart without leaving an entry in the logs about the shutdown?

Where should I look to further isolate the problem?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of faulty memory? While it would seem unlikely that the same hardware flaw would manifest in both computers, it might be the case that a manufacturing flaw could affect several machines in a particular production run. Tools like [Memtest86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86) can be useful in diagnosing memory issues. How about overheating issues? If the machines are co-located, similar temperature issues could affect them both.

Comment: A side note on kernel panic: The system can be configured to reboot after a specific delay, if a kernel panic occurred. And if you have Magic System Request keys enabled, you can reset a computer using the keyboard (or over the network, using the `ipt_sysrq` target). See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reboot-linux-box-after-a-kernel-panic.html and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reboot-or-halt-linux-system-in-emergency.html for details. But I would suspect the PSU as the cause first.

Comment: @ThomasNyman Doing a memtest is on my list. Overheating is very unlikely, the computers are in different rooms and one of them is in an airconditioned room.

Comment: @Abrixas2 I checked the option in /proc and it is set to 0, so it should not automatically reboot. The sysrq option is also not enabled.

Comment: Plug the computers into a UPS and see if it stops.  Most likely a small brownout that other equipment is not as sensitive to.

Comment: Does it always happen at the same time? How often does it happen? Does it happen at regular intervals? This could be a watchdog, is there a hardware or kernel watchdog?

Answer (score 1):

My first suspect would be the PSU. If you are not certain it's plenty powerful already, then try one which supports higher power output. Second I would try a different OS install to see if it could be triggered by software.

Comment: "behaves like a spontaneous loss of power" combined with "the computers are the only equipment affected each time" suggests that there is some internal protection circuit (e.g. undervoltage detector) kicking in and these two devices are unusually sensitive either because of defect in manufacture or electrical load from the controlled devices.